# Beautifulsoup Escaping Nested Tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following `HTML` document,

```
html_part = '''
    <h3>First Header</h3>
    First Header Content
    <h3>Second Header</h3>
    Second Header with some annoying tag </br>
    which ruins the extraction </br>
    <h3>Third Header</h3>
    This works fine
'''
```

And I am trying to extract all the content between the `h3` tags with the following program,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 


soup = BeautifulSoup(
    html_part,
    'html.parser'
)

for index in soup.find_all('h3'):
    print(
        index.next_sibling.string
    )
    print("-")
```

Which gives the following output,

```
First Header Content
-
Second Header with some annoying tag
-
This works fine
-
```

My desired output is the following,

```
First Header Content
-
Second Header with some annoying tag </br>
which ruins the extraction </br>
-
This works fine
-
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `soup.contents` to work through all the elements and keep track of when each `h3` tag is seen. For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

html_part = '''
    <h3>First Header</h3>
    First Header Content
    <h3>Second Header</h3>
    Second Header with some annoying tag </br>
    which ruins the extraction </br>
    <h3>Third Header</h3>
    This works fine
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_part, 'html.parser')
block = []
blocks = []
h3 = False

for el in soup.contents:
    if type(el) == Tag and el.name == 'h3':
        # Has a h3 tag been seen yet?
        if h3:
            blocks.append(block)
            block = []
        h3 = True
    elif h3:
        block.append(el)

# Add any final elements (missing a next h3)
if block:
    blocks.append(block)
    
for block in blocks:
    print(''.join(block))
    print('-')
```

This would give you:

```
    First Header Content
    
-

    Second Header with some annoying tag 
    which ruins the extraction 

-

    This works fine

-
```

Note: it is indented because your HTML is indented

---

If the content between the `h3` tags is more complicated and needs to be kept (rather than just text), you could further process them as soup:

```
for block in blocks:
    soup.contents = block
    print(soup)
    print('-')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It works, and seems robust. Will this work to extract all the contents regardless of the structure of the sibling?

Comment: As each element is stored in a list, you can convert it back as soup and further process (see the updated example). This should work for a more complex structure

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for this!